# Angular UI - grid always show in edit mode

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How to make angular ui grid always show the columns in edit mode?
I tried setting the cellTemplate to the editablecelltemplate but it did not work..
any idea here

Thanks,
Lokesh

Comment: try to set contentedittable =true

Comment: did the [documentation on the Edit Feature](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable) not have the options you need?

Comment: I could not see the option to set the always open the grid in edit mode...

Comment: Where to set this contenteditable = true.. in gridoptions?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you get your answer? Please post solution. contenteditable = true is not in ui grid i think.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this problem a year later... my solution was to mimic the edit template in cellTemplate:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="ui-grid/cellTitleValidator">
  <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="{{grid.validate.getTitleFormattedErrors(row.entity,col.colDef)}}">
    <div class="form-editor">
        <input ng-class="{'ng-invalid' : grid.validate.isInvalid(row.entity,col.colDef)}" value="{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}" placeholder="{{'platform.placeholders.n-a' | translate}}" readonly="readonly" />
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```